# DataTable reinitialisation error on looping through multiple tables and search in tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using DataTable to show 3 tables ('.dt') in separate tabs, along with a searching function. I'm getting a reinitialisation error whenever I load the page. This is my code:

```
            _datatables.forEach(function (datatable) {
                datatable.columns.adjust();
            });

        });

        function formatTable() {

            $('.dt').each(function () {

                var datatable;
                datatable = $(this).DataTable({
                    dom: '<"pull-left"f><"pull-right"l>tip',
                    scrollY: "400px",
                    scrollX: "100%",
                    paging: false,
                    bInfo: false,
                    searching: true,
                    order: [[0, "asc"]],
                    bRetrieve: true
                });

                datatable.columns.adjust();
                _datatables.push(datatable)
            });



        }
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_2 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3
```

Answer (score 0):

My simpler way of dealing with this would be, as given below. There are other ways too. it depends upon your situation. if you really do not want re-initialization just return instead of destroy.

```
function formatTable() {
         var tables = {};
         $('.dt').each(function () {
           if(tables[$(this).attr('id')]){
              tables[$(this).attr('id')].destroy();
              //return from here if you do not want to re-initialize
           }
           tables[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).DataTable({
                dom: '<"pull-left"f><"pull-right"l>tip',
                scrollY: "400px",
                scrollX: "100%",
                paging: false,
                bInfo: false,
                searching: true,
                order: [[0, "asc"]],
                bRetrieve: true
            });

            datatable.columns.adjust(); 
        });

    }
```

Comment: When I try this my scrolling and search function disappear on the second and third tabs. Any thoughts on how to keep that?

Comment: have you looked at line tables[$(this).attr('id')].destroy();
              //return from here if you do not want to re-initialize ? remove tables[$(this).attr('id')].destroy(); and put return;